How to apply "per-user access pricing" to users in Azure
we have an Azure environment and are planning to deploy Azure Virtual Desktop for our customers. We figured that we need per-user access pricing for licensing. So we enrolled the only Azure subscription we have as described in the guide.
However, the users we create for the customers don't cause costs in the cost analysis. Only the costs for the virtual machines and ressources are listed. How do I assign a user as external user to use per-user access pricing?
All guides I found just enable the per-user access pricing and that's it. It must be so obvious that it's not even worth mentioning. Like using cow milk in the cake instead of cat milk...
I appreciate all hints and tips.
